# Expose CiviDiscount Fields to Drupal Views

Tags: drupal-views, cividiscount

I'm creating a Drupal view and would like to reference the discount end date field created by the CiviDiscount extension, but the only thing associated with that extension that's available as a field is the "Default Discount Fee ID". 
Is there a way to access the other CiviDiscount fields from Drupal Views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on D7, you can use the [Views CiviCRM Expose Tables](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_civicrm_expose_tables) module.

Comment: I'm running Drupal 7.59 and this module doesn't seem to have an effect. I've installed and enabled it, and when I click the configuration icon next to it, I'm redirected to the views admin page (admin/structure/views). There don't seem to be any new fields available in the views fields.

Comment: Have you done this: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/views/#drupal-7 since enabling the CiviDiscount module?

Comment: I did have the databases set up properly but I hadn't cleared the caches. Clearing all Drupal cache's did the trick, thanks!